# DISTINCT / Unique

Tags: oracle

I am running a query that I want to return only the distinct `patron_id`.

```
SELECT
  pa.patron_account_id,
  pa.patron_account_name,
  pce.email,
  e.event_code AS EVENTCODE,
  sum(po.sales_revenue_amount),
  t.transaction_date
from event_seat es,
     buyer_type bt,
     event e,
     patron_account pa,
     patron_order po,
     sales_rep slsrep,
     season s,
     transaction t,
     patron_contact_address pca,
     patron_contact_email pce
where es.buyer_type_id = bt.buyer_type_id
  and es.event_id = e.event_id
  and es.financial_patron_account_id = pa.patron_account_id
  and es.order_id = po.order_id
  and po.sales_rep_id = slsrep.sales_rep_id (+)
  and e.season_id = s.season_id
  and es.transaction_id = t.transaction_id
  and pa.patron_account_id = pca.patron_account_id
  and pa.patron_account_id = pce.patron_account_id
  and s.season_code = '17ABC'
  and bt.buyer_type_code = 'ADULT'
  and e.event_code = '17ABCSEP23'
  --and e.event_id >= '1000' and e.event_id <= '1234'
  and pca.primary = '1'
  and pce.primary = '1'
group by pa.patron_account_id,
         pa.patron_account_name,
         pce.email,
         e.event_code,
         po.sales_revenue_amount,
         t.transaction_date
order by pa.patron_account_id;
```

Currently, my results have six instances of duplicates. For example, `patron_account_id` 123456 has two results, one for a `po.sales_revenue_amount` of $100 and a second for $80.

Ideally, I want my results to show 1 line item per `pa.patron_Account_id` with the aggregate `po.sales_revenue_amount` of $180

---

```
SELECT
 patron_account_id, 
 patron_account_name, 
 email, 
 EVENTCODE, 
 sum(sales_amt)

FROM 
  (SELECT 
   DISTINCT pa.patron_account_id,
   pa.patron_account_name,
   pce.email,
   e.event_code                  AS      EVENTCODE,
   sum(po.sales_revenue_amount)  AS      sales_amt

   from
   event_seat es,
   buyer_type bt,
   event e,
   patron_account pa,
   patron_order po,
   sales_rep slsrep,
   season s,
   transaction t,
   patron_contact_address pca,
   patron_contact_email pce

   where
   es.buyer_type_id = bt.buyer_type_id
   and es.event_id = e.event_id
   and es.financial_patron_account_id = pa.patron_account_id
   and es.order_id = po.order_id
   and po.sales_rep_id = slsrep.sales_rep_id (+)
   and e.season_id = s.season_id
   and es.transaction_id = t.transaction_id
   and pa.patron_account_id = pca.patron_account_id
   and pa.patron_account_id = pce.patron_account_id


   and s.season_code = '17123'
   and bt.buyer_type_code = 'ADULT'
   and e.event_code = '17ABCSEP23'
   --and e.event_id >= '5039' and e.event_id <= '5079'
   and pca.primary = '1'
   and pce.primary = '1'


   group by
   pa.patron_account_id,
   pa.patron_account_name,
   pce.email,
   e.event_code,
   po.sales_revenue_amount

   order by
   pa.patron_account_id)

GROUP BY  
patron_account_id, 
patron_account_name, 
email, 
EVENTCODE

ORDER BY 
patron_account_id;
```

Comment: You should consider changing your SQL query to use `JOIN` statements instead of Oracle proprietary `(+)` operations.

Comment: I am still quite new to SQL. How would that be structured as opposed to what I am currently doing

Comment: Showing it in a comment is not the greatest - But it would look like this: `SELECT <cols> FROM event_seats es JOIN buyer_type bt ON es.buyer_type_id = bt.buyer_type_id` etc ... `JOIN` will remove any records where the `ON` clause fails to find a match, where as `LEFT JOIN` will not remove records.

Comment: It moves your relationship requirements between tables out of the `WHERE` clause, closer to the table definitions, and makes the entire query more readable and understandable.

Comment: I'm not the best at reading the `(+)` since I have never used them, but I believe in this instance it's the equivalent of a `LEFT JOIN` .. (but it could be a `RIGHT JOIN` instead .. pretty sure it's left, though)

Comment: With the change of your question, we need to get some more information. Can there be more than one email, event code, or date per account ID? If so, how should the total sales revenue amount be shown? For instance, do you want the total revenue per date? if there are multiple email addresses, do you want to see both email addresses, or just one? If you have one row with each of the patron's email addresses, do you show the full revenue on both lines? (It doesn't look like revenue is tied to one address or the other).

Comment: Each time a patron account id makes a purchase, a new row would be added. So, the patron_account_id cannot have more than one e-mail address, however can have more than one transaction date. My ideal output would be all of the unique patron_account_id's and the total po.sales_revenue_amount that each pa.patron_account_id purchased given the parameters of this unique event code. Hope that helps clarify

Comment: A couple of notes: 1) `DISTINCT` should be unnecessary when you also have a `GROUP BY`; 2) Generally, `ORDER BY` in a sub-query is unnecessary - in some SQL variants, it's not allowed; 3) Your sub-query alone should give the same results as your outer query, if you drop the `DISTINCT`, and remove `po.sales_revenue_amount` from the sub-query's `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Sounds like (and I think you've figured this out) the date should be left out of the query altogether. You also should drop `po.sales_revenue_amount` from the `GROUP BY` clause; otherwise, you'll still get a separate row for each unique `sales_revenue_amount` in your data, instead of a total for the account and event code. Also (for future reference) it would have helped to have included sample data, your current output, and your desired output - that generally makes it clear what you're trying to do, and what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Then you should use the aggregate function SUM:

```
SELECT pa.patron_account_id, sum(po.sales_revenue_amount)
  FROM SOURCE
 GROUP BY pa.patron_account_id;
```

Comment: This still produced the same undesired result. I have more columns that I added into my original post above

Comment: @EvanBarrick - Consider the answer in terms of what the question was at the time Martin answered it. You should be able to get the same relative results if you make the same changes to your new query.

Comment: I did add what Martin suggested to the entire query and did not get the desired results